# making a mass invoke required

Tags: c#, winforms

I've developed a user-control class which i intent to use for buttons . After declaring them in my form1 class, i use something like this : `inout_button1.click += new EventHandler(but1);` to add a handler for the click . all is well till here. from another thread i wish to invoke a method in my form1 class that changes the state of the button (Enabled=true/false, built in the user-control class ) but i am told by the program that i can't access it from another thread. My question is : Can i make a invoke in my button class and not for every button ? i have some like 14 buttons so it's kind of uneasy to make a delegate for all of them, one by one ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not amend your UI controls from threads other than UI thread, for this reason there is a work around. Please take a look [into this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What does the event handler have to do with your Button's state?

But yes, if you create a SetState method in your Button you can use **Invoke**() once in this method to make this method safe to call from another thread.

Comment: i just wanted to point out that the eventHandler was declared outside my class, just thought to give more details..